# how to create instance while name was known at runtime and do fast

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I have several windows form applications.  I am designing a new windows form application to make users open a form from another application by clicking a button or from menu,etc.  That is,  the form name and which app contains that form was known only at runtime when users select a function.

```
dim asmTemp as System.Reflection.Assembly=System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(anotherEXE)
newForm=asmTemp.CreateInstance(asmTemp.EntryPoint.ReflectedType.Namespace & FormName)
```

I can create a new form by the code shown upper, but it takes several seconds.  Is it a faster way to open a form from another exe while the form name and exe name are known at runtime?

Comment: No, that's not going to make a noticeable difference.  If you have no idea why code takes a long time then you should use a profiler.

Comment: Now I know the app spend much time on `assembly.CreateInstance` while creating form from another EXE.  How can I know why so slow by the profiler?  Can I see what happened inside the subroutine?